# Spectral norm is smaller than trace

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, trace

How can I prove this inequality?

For any even number $k$ and symmetric matrix $A$,

$||A||^{k}\leq Tr(A^{k})$

where ||.|| stands form the spectral norm and $Tr$ for the trace of the matrix.

Comment: If $k=1$ then $E [\operatorname{tr} A] = \operatorname{tr}(E[ A]) =0$ but the left hand side is positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true because for every real symmetric $A$, we have $\|A\|^{2k}\le\operatorname{tr}(A^{2k})$, or equivalently, $\left(|\lambda|_\max(A)\right)^{2k}\le\sum_i\lambda_i(A)^{2k}$.

Comment: You assumed $||A^{2k}||=||A||^{2k}$ here. Is it always true?

Comment: @KürşatZubizerreta This is true because $A$ is real symmetric.

Comment: Thank you for the solution!